# Why do I have to wait several minutes before "USB 2.0 Hub" shows up in "System Information..." -> "USB Device Tree"?

Tags: keyboard, usb, mouse, thunderbolt

Recently, after connecting a USB 2.0 hub to my MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, i5). I need to wait several minutes before I can see it in "System Information..." -> "USB" -> "USB 3.0 Bus" section.

[image]

This is very inconvenient. Because I need to connect my keyboard and mouse to this USB hub. If "USB 2.0 Hub" doesn't show up under USB Device Tree, I can't use my keyboard and mouse.

Why does this happen?

I've tried both of the Thunderbolt ports of the MacBook Pro. But the same problem occurs, I still need to wait several minutes before "USB 2.0 Hub" shows up under "USB Device Tree".

You can find the above window by holding *option* key, clicking the apple icon on the top left corner of your screen, then clicking *System Information...*.

I've also tried using another USB hub, but the problem still exists.

Does anyone know what might be the root cause of this problem and how to fix it?

I've tried resetting NVRAM by following [this tutorial](https://www.sweetwater.com/sweetcare/articles/how-to-reset-pram-or-nvram/#How-to-Reset-PRAM-or-NVRAM). But it doesn't help.

Could this mean that my MacBook Pro doesn't have enough current to drive the USB hub, so it needs extra time to identify the USB hub?

Comment: I’ve seen keyboards with nkey rollover cause issues.  Do you have this feature?  Can you try a plain, no-frills, cheap, USB keyboard to see if you have problems with it?

Comment: & try break the problem into smaller parts. See if plugging just the hub in causes it to appear any quicker, or just hub, then mouse... etc

Comment: Hi, @Allan. I don't have a cheap keyboard by my side now. I can try using a cheaper keyboard and mouse after a few days.

Comment: No problem.  It’s always good to keep a spare keyboard as backup. I have a cheap-ish Logitech wireless (unifring receiver) keyboard with built in trackpad for backup.  There’s probably a dell wired keyboard in a box in the garage too.  It’s a cheap fix in a pinch.

Comment: Hi, @Allan. Using a cheaper keyboard and mouse doesn't help. This same problem still exists.

Comment: Is it direct or through a hub?

Comment: Through a USB hub. The keyboard and mouse I have can't connect directly to my MacBook Pro.